# Bootstrap 4 not responsive in Chrome

Tags: mobile, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, responsive

I've created a small email signature with Bootstrap 4 which displays correctly in Firefox (v 69.0.1):

It doesn't display responsively in Chrome, in Safari on a mobile, or in the Gmail app.

Am I missing something completely obvious?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
Bob

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 introduced a method to let web designers take control over the viewport, through the  tag... You need to add the tag below in the `<head>`... for more information [here](http://%3Cmeta%20name=%22viewport%22%20content=%22width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no%22%3E)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">
```

**Update**: you URL working as expected after adding the link above (screenshot below)

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, but that didn't make a difference :(

Comment: Hi @bob32 which device are you using? still not responsive after a hard refresh? I got the correct result on my iPhone (updated the answer with the result also)